# yum update fails with "ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:" but no packages listed in conflict

Tags: linux, yum, amazon-ami

I ran into a situation where `yum update` started failing on a AMI instance. Was trying to install openVPN when it all started. I used the following command to get easy-rsa `sudo yum install easy-rsa -y --enablerepo=epel` then later did a `sudo yum update`, I am guessing at this point something was installed from epel that was a later version then what was in the standard amazon repos, as I hit the "ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:" with some conflicting packages. I removed the offending packages using yum, removed epel repo, ran `sudo yum clean all` and tried to update again. Now when I run `sudo yum update` I get the results at the bottom. It shows a transaction check error but there are no conflicting packages from what I can tell.

I have ran the following and nothing has worked,

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
sudo yum clean all
```

Output of yum now:

```
Total size: 403 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
libgcc48(x86-32) = 4.8.3 is needed by (installed) gcc48-4.8.3-9.109.amzn1.i686
lvm2-libs = 2.02.100-8.22.amzn1 is needed by (installed) lvm2-2.02.100-8.22.amzn1.i686
setools-libs = 3.3.7-24.17.amzn1 is needed by (installed) setools-console-3.3.7-24.17.amzn1.i686
setools-libs = 3.3.7-24.17.amzn1 is needed by (installed) setools-libs-tcl-3.3.7-24.17.amzn1.i686
libxml2 = 2.9.1-3.1.35.amzn1 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python27-2.9.1-3.1.35.amzn1.i686
libstdc++48-devel(x86-32) = 4.8.3-9.109.amzn1 is needed by (installed) gcc48-c++-4.8.3-9.109.amzn1.i686
mysql51-libs(x86-32) = 5.1.73-3.69.amzn1 is needed by (installed) mysql51-5.1.73-3.69.amzn1.i686
e2fsprogs-libs(x86-32) = 1.42.9-4.33.amzn1 is needed by (installed) e2fsprogs-1.42.9-4.33.amzn1.i686
libproxy = 0.3.0-4.8.amzn1 is needed by (installed) libproxy-bin-0.3.0-4.8.amzn1.i686
libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8 is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8(kadm5clnt_mit_8_MIT) is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
libkadm5srv_mit.so.8 is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
libkadm5srv_mit.so.8(kadm5srv_mit_8_MIT) is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
libkdb5.so.6 is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
libkdb5.so.6(kdb5_6_MIT) is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
krb5-libs = 1.10.3-10.26.amzn1 is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.10.3-10.26.amzn1.i686
elfutils-libelf(x86-32) = 0.158-3.16.amzn1 is needed by (installed) elfutils-0.158-3.16.amzn1.i686
glibc = 2.17-55.87.amzn1 is needed by (installed) glibc-common-2.17-55.87.amzn1.i686
bind-libs = 32:9.8.2-0.23.rc1.32.amzn1 is needed by (installed) bind-utils-32:9.8.2-0.23.rc1.32.amzn1.i686
mysql51-common = 5.1.73-3.69.amzn1 is needed by (installed) mysql51-5.1.73-3.69.amzn1.i686
nss(x86-32) = 3.19.1-5.73.amzn1 is needed by (installed) nss-tools-3.19.1-5.73.amzn1.i686
libselinux = 2.1.10-3.17.amzn1 is needed by (installed) libselinux-utils-2.1.10-3.17.amzn1.i686
xz-libs = 5.1.2-8alpha.11.amzn1 is needed by (installed) xz-5.1.2-8alpha.11.amzn1.i686
libstdc++48(x86-32) = 4.8.3-9.109.amzn1 is needed by (installed) gcc48-c++-4.8.3-9.109.amzn1.i686
kmod-libs(x86-32) = 14-9.9.amzn1 is needed by (installed) kmod-14-9.9.amzn1.i686
libattr = 2.4.44-7.9.amzn1 is needed by (installed) attr-2.4.44-7.9.amzn1.i686
perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-283.37.amzn1 is needed by (installed) perl-4:5.16.3-283.37.amzn1.i686
libss = 1.42.9-4.33.amzn1 is needed by (installed) e2fsprogs-1.42.9-4.33.amzn1.i686
elfutils-libs(x86-32) = 0.158-3.16.amzn1 is needed by (installed) elfutils-0.158-3.16.amzn1.i686
rpm-build-libs(x86-32) = 4.11.2-2.70.amzn1 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.11.2-2.70.amzn1.i686
libacl = 2.2.49-6.9.amzn1 is needed by (installed) acl-2.2.49-6.9.amzn1.i686
rpm-libs(x86-32) = 4.11.2-2.70.amzn1 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.11.2-2.70.amzn1.i686
tcp_wrappers-libs = 7.6-75.11.amzn1 is needed by (installed) tcp_wrappers-7.6-75.11.amzn1.i686
libcom_err(x86-32) = 1.42.9-4.33.amzn1 is needed by (installed) e2fsprogs-1.42.9-4.33.amzn1.i686
file-libs = 5.19-4.19.amzn1 is needed by (installed) file-5.19-4.19.amzn1.i686
device-mapper-libs = 1.02.79-8.22.amzn1 is needed by (installed) device-mapper-1.02.79-8.22.amzn1.i686
audit-libs = 2.3.3-4.21.amzn1 is needed by (installed) audit-2.3.3-4.21.amzn1.i686
python27-libs(x86-32) = 2.7.10-4.119.amzn1 is needed by (installed) python27-2.7.10-4.119.amzn1.i686
libcurl(x86-32) = 7.40.0-3.52.amzn1 is needed by (installed) curl-7.40.0-3.52.amzn1.i686
device-mapper-event-libs = 1.02.79-8.22.amzn1 is needed by (installed) device-mapper-event-1.02.79-8.22.amzn1.i686
cryptsetup-libs(x86-32) = 1.6.3-2.14.amzn1 is needed by (installed) cryptsetup-1.6.3-2.14.amzn1.i686
glib2 = 2.36.3-5.16.amzn1 is needed by (installed) glib2-devel-2.36.3-5.16.amzn1.i686
ruby18-libs(x86-32) = 1.8.7.374-2.42.3.amzn1 is needed by (installed) ruby18-1.8.7.374-2.42.3.amzn1.i686
apr-util(x86-32) = 1.4.1-4.14.amzn1 is needed by (installed) apr-util-ldap-1.4.1-4.14.amzn1.i686
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-06-18.19-00.K4yo5K.yumtx
```